# Склонение слова "Интернет"

Tags: морфология

Как правильно просклонять слово "Интернет"?

Answer (score 1):

Слово уже вполне "обрусело", так что склоняется по образцу слов мужского рода II склонения: интернет, интернета, интернету, интернет, интернетом, интернете.

Answer (score 1):

В словарях (Лопатина, Кузнецова и др.) "Интернет" по-прежнему даётся с заглавной буквы. 
Изменяется по падежам при самостоятельном использовании (Интернета, Интернету), но при использоании с родовым словом склоняется только оно (в сети Интернет).

Comment: Спасибо за заглаВную букву:-)